# how to send response only when a function is complete using promises

Tags: node.js, promise

how to send the response only when a particular function is completed. i tried using promises for this but this doesnt seem to work.

```
let dealPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
for (let  i = 0;i < deals.length;i++) {
  let link = 'https://api.cortellis.com/api-ws/ws/rs/deals-v2/deal/' + deals[i] + '?fmt=json';
  let options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: link,
    auth: auth,
  };
  let constant = constants.collection('clarivate');

  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    body = JSON.parse(body).dealRecordOutput;
    if (body.length === 0) {
      res.status(204).json({'data': []});
      next();
    }
    else {
      let type = body.Type;
      type_list.push(type);
      let status_val = body.Status;
      status_list.push(status_val);

      resp['type'] = type_list;
      resp['status'] = status_list;

       }
      });
    }
    resolve(resp);
  });

  dealPromise.then(function (result) {
    res.status(200).json({'data': result});
  });
```

is there any other way to go around this?

Comment: Where is the mysterious `resp` declared?

Comment: and `type_list` and `status_list`

Comment: Your code does not really show your desired functionality.  Open questions.  When you get `body.length === 0` in the middle of your iteration, what do you want to happen?  FYI, calling `next()` after you've sent a response is never what you want to do either.  What are you trying to do with `type_list` and `status_list` and `resp`?  What is `result`?  I have a new structure for doing this mostly written, but without these answers I can't post something that would work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing multiple requests by using `for` that are resolved even after that your promise is resolved.

I would do this:

```
const myPromises = Promise.all(deals.map(deal => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // ... do your request here
        // call resolve in the callback request 
    })
}))

myPromises.then(result => {
    // ... here all your requests have been resolved
    // call res.status(200).json({...})
})
```

Comment: `new Promise(...)` can (and should) be avoided completely. `[request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)`, will allow `return request(...).then(...)` inside the .map callback.

Comment: Yes, we know that, I'm just trying take the code that was already written, that's gonna make easier to get the idea behind of Promises.all.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to the `request-promise` library for doing your requests, then it will return a promise for each request and you can then use `Promise.all()` to know when they are all done.

Your code is a bit incomplete on a number of topics such as what do when you encounter an empty body and how exactly you want to build the final `result` data.  So, allowing you to fill in those details, here's a general structure that would work for you:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

let type_list = [], status_list = [];
Promise.all(deals.map(item => {
    let options = {
        method: 'GET',
        uri: 'https://api.cortellis.com/api-ws/ws/rs/deals-v2/deal/' + item + '?fmt=json',
        auth: auth
    };
    let constant = constants.collection('clarivate');
    return rp(options).then(body => {
        if (body.length !== 0) {
            try {
                let data = JSON.parse(body).dealRecordOutput;
                type_list.push(data.Type);
                status_list.push(data.Status)
            } catch(e) {
                // log and skip items with bad JSON
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    });
})).then(() => {
    // all requests done here
    let result = {};
    // put code here to create result using type_list and status_list
    res.status(200).json({data: result});
}).catch(err => {
    // got an error in one of the requests
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
});
```